# WPF buttons are outside the datacontext and could not be bound

Tags: wpf, binding, controls, datacontext

[image]Hello,

I have 3 Buttons add,delete,open as **RelayCommands** in my **DocumentViewModel**.
Below you see how I have bound them. Of course those binding does not work, because the data is set to the **ItemsSource** of the **ListBox** and the buttons are **outside** of that...

What I tried then is to set the DataContext at the first StackPanel you see in my code snippet.

like this: `<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding DocumentViewModelList}" >`

BUT then a new problem arised... now the documents are NOT visible/listed anymore in the ListBox :/

***How can I make BOTH working?***

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                                            <ListBox 
                                                Height="100"
                                                Width="Auto"
                                                Focusable="True"
                                                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                                Grid.Row="1" 
                                                Name="itemListBox"
                                                BorderThickness="1"      
                                                ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentViewModelList}"
                                                >
                                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel>      
                                                            <!-- xxx -->
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>                                                  
                                                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}" />
                                                        </Style>                                                  
                                                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                            </ListBox>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">                                                
                                                <Button Command="{Binding DeleteDocumentCommand}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Delete" />
                                                <Button Command="{Binding    AddDocumentCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Add" />
                                                <Button Command="{Binding   OpenDocumentCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Open" />                                               
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
```

**UPDATE**:

**I tried this**:

```
 <Button Command="{Binding Path=DeleteDocumentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DocumentViewModel}}}"
```

**and got this**: The type reference cannot find a public type named 'DocumentViewModel'

I would like to stick with the StackPanel DataContext solution and make somehow the ListBox.ItemsSource grabbing the DocumentViewModelList via RelativeSource binding with FindAncestor. I tried some things but no luck, maybe someone can post a nice snippet :)

OK I found the solution: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" ..`.

this is binding to the current DataContext that is "DocumentViewModelList" cool!

**UPDATE 2:**

ok there is still another problem, maybe if someone can provide a solution on this I mark this thread as a solution then. Do not want to open a new thread, because the whole text+code snippet is the same... Problem now is =>Selecting The 1st Document activates the Button. Selecting any other Button does not activate a Button, WHY? What is wrong with the binding of my IsSelected property ?

DocumentViewModel.cs:

```
private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected 
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                if (_isSelected == value)
                    return;

                _isSelected = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

This is the code for enabling the buttons: What do I wrong? I get no binding errors in the output console!?

```
private void DeleteDocument()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private bool CanDeleteDocument()
        {
            return (IsSelected == true);
        }

        private void AddDocument()
        { 

        }

        private void OpenDocument()
        { 

        }

        public RelayCommand DeleteDocumentCommand
        {
            get { return _deleteDocumentCommand ?? (_deleteDocumentCommand = new RelayCommand(() => DeleteDocument(), () => CanDeleteDocument())); }
        }

        public RelayCommand AddDocumentCommand
        {
            get { return _addDocumentCommand ?? (_addDocumentCommand = new RelayCommand(() => AddDocument())); }
        }

        public RelayCommand OpenDocumentCommand
        {
            get { return _openDocumentCommand ?? (_openDocumentCommand = new RelayCommand(() => OpenDocument())); }
        }
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but I don't know how much help it will be.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the `DocumentViewModelList` a property of your `DocumentViewModel`?

Typically, what I would have is a ViewModel for that window which would expose an `ObservableCollection<T>` where `T` is what you want displayed in the list.  Then, you can assign the Window/Page/etc.'s `DataContext` to the ViewModel, and then bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` to that `ObservableCollection<T>` property.

For example, here would be a snippet of my ViewModel.

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<SingleDocumentViewModel> Docs {get; private set; }

  // other properties can go here
}
```

In the code-behind for the XAML, (I usually do it in the constructor), you can set its `DataContext` to a new instance of your ViewModel

```
public AwesomeDocumentList()
{
  this.DataContext = new SomeViewModel();
  // the rest of the constructor
}
```

With the Window's DataContext set, you can bind the `ItemsSource` to the exposed property (I called it `Docs`)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Docs}" ... />
```

Hope that helps.

**Update**

In the `RelayCommand` for the button, do you have something specified for the `CanExecute` predicate?  If not, then I believe the `RelayCommand` will default to always enabled.  But if you have a predicate specified, take a look in there.

The code you posted for the `IsSelected` property looks fine.  Looks like the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @Lisa Eric's solution is absolutely correct. If you are having so much trouble doing what you want to do, there is a problem in the way you have set up the ViewModel. Try simplifyling everything and start from scratch. You'll quickly find the problem.

Comment: @For the first solution I helped myself. And his 2nd solution is no help. My ViewModels are setup correctly. My problem could something have to do with this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a2394616-9cbf-400d-b632-284cc56a2666 but I tried all the suggestions and nothing helped. I will open a new thread @Eric Due to your help I accept your solution although I was faster ;P am too busy to write a solution answer now...

Comment: @NVM if you think I have setup something wrongly, check this out! => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695719/isselected-property-of-viewmodel-bound-to-listbox-only-first-item-selection-work